# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException occurred

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

So I have made a custom controller by parsing objects in a model to a database in my project and inside that controller, there is a post method called `Edit` which includes the database fields such as **Id, Title, Description, FileName, FileType, FileSize, Author,DateUploaded**

In the edit html view, I removed some elements because all I want to edit is "Title" and "Description" and I have also removed the fields in the `edit` method in the controller I created.

To explain that;

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = FileSharing "Id,Title,Description,FileName,FileType,FileSize,Author,DateUploaded")] FileSharing fileSharing)
```

into:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Description")] FileSharing fileSharing)
```

When I try to edit a title or description. It will give a exception error saying

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Why am I getting this error and how can I get around it?

`Edit` method

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Description")] FileSharing fileSharing)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Entry(fileSharing).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ViewBag.EditFail = "Error editing file details.";
            }
        }
        return View(fileSharing);
    }
```

Comment: where is the database update occuring. Show the relevant code.

Comment: The exception is generated inside of your action method probably on `dbContext.SaveChanges()`. You should wrap this call in a try/catch block and then view the complete exception and inner exception(s), EF is pretty good at detailing the exact cause of an exception. If you still need help then provide the complete exception details as well as the complete code in the action.

Comment: @user1666620 Updated my post.

Comment: Please provide the complete Exception. Wrap the `db.SaveChanges()` in a try/catch. Just the top-level exception is not enough.

Comment: @Igor Done. Updated my post. It doesn't crash anymore. It just still does not edit and it says ""Error editing file details."  which I have put for the exception.

Comment: @Justin - What I meant was that we need you to capture the exception and tell us what that exception is. Not just the type/message of the top level exception but for each inner exception we need the type/message as well. Now you are doing nothing more than swallowing the exception which is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I handle that exception.

```
private Exception HandleDbUpdateException(DbUpdateException dbu)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder("A DbUpdateException was caught while saving changes. ");
            if (!(dbu.InnerException is System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException) ||
                !(dbu.InnerException.InnerException is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var result in dbu.Entries)
                    {
                        builder.AppendFormat("Type: {0} was part of the problem. ", result.Entity.GetType().Name);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    builder.Append("Error parsing DbUpdateException: " + e);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var sqlException = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)dbu.InnerException.InnerException;
                for (int i = 0; i < sqlException.Errors.Count; i++)
                {
                    builder.AppendLine("    SQL Message: " + sqlException.Errors[i].Message);
                    builder.AppendLine("    SQL procedure: " + sqlException.Errors[i].Procedure);
                }
            }

            string message = builder.ToString();
            return new Exception(message, dbu);
        }
```

Then at least the exception has more relevant information, which probably makes it easy for you to figure out what's wrong (like some DB validation issue).