# More info about DbUpdateException while deleting entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having some troubles with handling UpdateException. I mean, i know what is casuing it ( it is thrown after I want to delete Group which still contains Students ). But is it possible to get from that exception information, which constraint is being broken or something similar so i could give a proper info to user of my application ? Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742749/system-data-entity-infrastructure-dbupdateexception-occurred/32744231#32744231

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490842/finding-the-reason-for-dbupdateexception

Comment: Create a breakpoint where the error is occurring, run the website in debug mode,  and then look at the inner exception.